# how to configure local ant script on remote jenkins/hudson

Tags: jenkins

I have a build.xml file in my local system. How to configure teh same in a jenkins/hudson service, present in remote server.
If the master/slave concept i the only way, can anyone give detailed steps to follow to configure the same?
NOTE: my local system runs under windows platform, jenkins is present on linux server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you get the source code from some version control system. You should put the build file into the same version control system, so that it can be checked out and run by Jenkins.